# StamplayApp request time out error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, linkedin-api, stamplay

I am trying to app the linkedIN login. When I sign in through linkedIn, it opens a new page and redirects to

> https://demostore.stamplayapp.com/auth/v1/Linkedin/connect

but throws an

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 () 
>   https://demostore.stamplayapp.com/auth/v1/Linkedin/connect

the  https://demostore.stamplayapp.com/auth/v1/Linkedin/connect is the one I put is the Authorized Redirect URLs I placed in the Linked in developer.

Comment: Hey noor the redirect URL that you need to configure on LinkedIn should be  https://demostore.stamplayapp.com/auth/v1/Linkedin/callback. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: LinkedIn doesn't allow me to add that. It gives me this error 'OAuth 2.0 redirect URLs must be HTTP or HTTPS.'

Comment: Hey noor you need to configure in the OAuth1 callback URL field